# How send date param via http request to Google Form?

Tags: http, google-forms

I would like to sned data from my mobile app via http request to Google Form. The problem is that I need to send date. Here the link

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/PAGE_ID/formResponse?entry.1748727384=1&entry.1949164265=1&entry.168813548=29.10.2015&submit=Submit
```

But when I have sent it, I see that my Form wasn't filled, and it shows that date is empty. It seems that I use wrong format for transfer date. So how can I send date using http request? I also used timestamp, but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

So I solved this problem. I opened it via Mozilla Firefox and noticed that there are 3 more fields for date. So I just found the id of this field and write it for separate values like this:
    entry.168813548_day=10&entry.168813548_month=2&entry.168813548_year=2015